# Swift console typing animation

Tags: swift

So, I am new to swift, and I wanted a typing animation in the console for swift, and I tried to make one on my own, like this:

```swift
import Foundation
let line = "Hello"
for char in line {
  print(char, terminator: "")
  Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
}
```

But for some reason the terminator didn't listen to the next line and wait the repeat. If I didn't use terminator, it worked great, but put each one one on a new line.

Can someone please help me make this work?

NOTE: I AM NOT USING XCODE